# get_category_link returning page URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am using the following code to display a list of categories in a custom taxonomy, except the URL returns only the current page URL.

```
<?php $category_ids = get_all_category_ids(); ?>
  <?php
  $args = array(
     'orderby' => 'slug',
     'parent' => 0,
    'taxonomy' => 'servicecats',
    'hide_empty' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
      $imgurl = z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id); 
      echo '<li><img src="'. $imgurl . '"/><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '' . '' . $category->description . '</a></li>'; 
}
 ?>
```

I have read in other topics I should be using get_term_link but this gave me an error, also changed get_categories to get_terms and my categories disappeared off the screen.
How can I get this URL to link to the category please?

Comment: As you found in your answer, you have to use `get_term_link()` because it's a custom taxonomy. One debugging tip though: it probably didn't return the current page URL, it likely returned nothing - your browser interprets that as a link to the current page. Debugging tip is to check your HTML source for clues; you'd probably see `<a href="">` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed get_category_link to:

```
esc_attr(get_term_link($category, 'servicecats'))
```

Thanks to [this site](http://www.themikeross.com/wordpressget_category_link-doesnt-work)